# How to format NSString to include Dash in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, format, uitextfield

I have a UITextfield that contains a credit card number. I want to convert the credit card number that the user inputs in the UITextField to have dashes. An example would be:

From: 1021 3151 1641 3546

To: 1021-3151-1641-3546

I'll put the method in the textFieldShouldEndEditing method. Would someone provide the right code for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(NSString*)appendDash:(NSString*)str
{
    NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString stringWithString:str];
   //remove the white spaces of original string
    [string replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
    int num = [string length];
    for (int i = 4;i<= num; i++) {
        [string insertString:@"-" atIndex:i];
        i+=4;
    }
    return string;
}
```

Comment: I want to know the reason why the " " string must be replaced with "" string first before inserting the hyphen. Why not directly change " " with "-"?

Comment: a white space is read as one character.the code will insert a string every after 4 characters in loop. i had to remove the whitespaces so I can have the exact char count.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the whitespace with "-"

```
 yourStr=[yourStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"-"];
```